# Splitting subfolders of an SVN repo into individual Mercurial repos results in error "abort: expected trunk to be at 'trunk/module1', but not found"

Tags: mercurial

I have an SVN repo with structure like this:

/branch
/tags
/trunk
/trunk/module1
/trunk/module2
/trunk/module3

I am trying to separate this into individual Mercurial repos, where each new Mercurial repo retains the revision history of that module's files.  The end result would be

/module1-hg
/module2-hg
/module3-hg

Based on this guide (http://wiki.colar.net/selectively_converting_subversion_repository_to_mercurial),
I have tried using

```
hg --config convert.svn.trunk=trunk/module1 convert https://repo.url/ module1-hg
```

but that results in the following error:

```
abort: expected trunk to be at 'trunk/module1', but not found
```

I am able to convert the whole SVN repository, but I'd really like to separate the modules at this point. I feel like I just can't find a good example of the syntax to split these apart.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did this but I did it in several steps.

Firstly, I converted the whole repo to be a mirror of the SVN repo.  I used the `hgsubversion` extension for this but if you've done it using the `convert` extension then that's fine.

The second step was where I split the repos up.  I used the `convert` extension with a filemap to exclude some folders and rename others.

For example:

```
hg convert bigrepo module1-hg --filemap module1.txt
```

And `module1.txt` would contain the following:

```
exclude module2
exclude module3
rename module1 .
```

That would create a repo called module1-hg excluding modules 2 and 3.  It would also move the source of module1 into the root of the repo instead of a subdirectory.

You could then repeat the action for modules 2 and 3 with similar filemap files.